# How to make Ctrl+= behave like Ctrl+w = in Vim?

Tags: vim

A lot of times I find myself using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>, which resizes all windows equally. However, when I add `nnoremap <C-=> <C-w>=` to my .vimrc and restart vim, windows don't resize after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>.

How do I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> behave like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> ?

Comment: If in insertion mode you type CTRL-V then CTRL-=, what gets written to the buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Vim FAQ](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5) this is because Vim can only map key combinations that have an ASCII equivalent, and there is no ASCII equivalent for `<C-=>`.